# pg_dump version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a remote postgres DB version 10.8 setup on a linux. I am trying to back it up on windows machine using postgres 9.6.12

```bash
pg_dump --host dahost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format tar --blobs --verbose --file "path\noury.backup" "highlands_wastewater"
```

I get these errors

```
pg_dump: server version: 10.8 (Ubuntu 10.8-0ubuntu0.18.04.1); pg_dump version: 9.6.12
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

How can I backup this database remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you cannot use an older version of `pg_dump` with a newer PostgreSQL Version.

The reason behind that is that PostgreSQL 9.6 cannot know how to dump a v10 database properly — there may be new features in the newer version (for example, partitioned tables).

You'll have to install PostgreSQL v10 or later on your Windows machine (exactly v10 if you want to be able to restore the dump to the original database).

Don't use the `tar` format. The `custom` format offers more advantages.